# How can I unselect text after it has been highlighted?

Tags: c#, wpf, text, selection

The code below highlights the text after it is found, but my issues is I can't clear the the highlighted text when you search for a word that cant be found.

My question is how do I set the selection to empty so the text is no longer highlighted?
code that Highlights the text after it is found:

```
 IsTextSelected = true;
 _body.Selection.Select(foundRange.Start, foundRange.End);
 _body.SelectionBrush = selectionHighlighter;
  newSearch = false;
```

Code when text is not found:

```
MessageBox.Show("\'" + searchBox.Text.Trim() + "\' not found!");
newSearch = true;
lastOffset = -1;
IsTextSelected = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a TextBox, set the [SelectionLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionlength.aspx) property to zero.

For a RichTextBox:

```
rtb.Selection.Select(rtb.Selection.Start, rtb.Selection.Start);
```

Comment: i dont have a selectionlenght property

Comment: What type of control is it, if it isn't a textbox?